# Need help validating token - I cannot read JSON response data

Tags: angularjs, google-oauth

I am having problem reading the JSON response data after sending Google OAuth2 token validation request per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken).

**Here is the Google OAuth2 token validation request:**

```
$http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo', {params: {access_token: accessToken.token}})
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $log.info("sendValidationRequest() method: data: " + data);
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                    accessToken.state = getSession().state = $window.sessionStorage.state = "AccessTokenValidated";
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    //handle error
                });
```

So when I inspect that JSON response data object I get the following:

```
data.audience; // undefined
data.scope; // undefined
data.userid; // undefined
data.expires_in; //undefined
```

This is what the JSON Response data looks like inside Chrome Developer Tools:
[image]

I was expecting the JSON response data to be a JSON Array per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken).
The JSON response data seems to be encoded.  How do I resolve this?

**Here is my HTTP Header Request:**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?
access_token=ya29.AHES6ZQBj6feCrXuDoqwA3FpX1T1HO8fH1eWegJbiBTp7Cs HTTP/1.1
:host: www.googleapis.com
origin: http://localhost:8080
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
:path: /oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?  access_token=ya29.AHES6ZQBj6feCrXuDoqwA3FpX1T1HO8fH1eWegJbiBTp7Cs
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
:version: HTTP/1.1
referer: http://localhost:8080/calendar-app/
:scheme: https
:method: GET
```

**Here is my HTTP Response Header:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
status: 200 OK
version: HTTP/1.1
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:8080
access-control-expose-headers: Cache-Control,Content-Encoding,Content-Length,Content-Type,Date,Expires,Pragma,Server
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 182
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
date: Sat, 17 Aug 2013 08:00:05 GMT
expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
server: GSE
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

Any help with resolving my issue is much appreciated.

Thank you.

After doing some research, I found that this a problem specific to AngularJS $http services; as this is not a problem with JQuery.  Here is what my validate access token code looks like in JQuery:

```
function validateToken() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=' + accessToken,
            data: null,
            success: function(response){
                console.log('Our token is valid. and response.audience value is defined.');
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log('Our token is not valid....');
            },
            dataType: "jsonp"
        });
    }
```

**The JQuery Ajax request headers are different request headers are different from $http service request header (See above):**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=ya29.AHES6ZTewZF3-aEJ3p8mdJahvTtZDNELYjpqLsGaB10Fnmk&callback=jQuery172036758901784196496_1376731301308&_=1376731301856 HTTP/1.1
:host: www.googleapis.com
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
:path: /oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=ya29.AHES6ZTewZF3-aEJ3p8mdJahvTtZDNELYjpqLsGaB10Fnmk&callback=jQuery172036758901784196496_1376731301308&_=1376731301856
accept: */*
:version: HTTP/1.1
referer: http://localhost:8080/calendar-app/google-oauth-test2.html
:scheme: https
:method: GET
```

**Which in turns the Google Response headers are different when the request was issued by $http service (See Above):**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
status: 200 OK
version: HTTP/1.1
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 235
content-type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
date: Sat, 17 Aug 2013 09:21:40 GMT
expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
server: GSE
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

So now the question becomes, how to get AngularJS $http service request headers to match what JQuery's AJAX request headers look like?  Or is there another way to get the same result; which is to get the proper JSON array object back from google after a successful access token validation?

Again, any help with this is much appreciated!

I am updating post because there seems to be some questions of whether or not I have a space in the URL and that I am not show the raw JSON response.  I hope this picture from chrome Developer's Tools clears this up.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is your HTTP response payload? The raw JSON response.

Comment: I show the response tab my first picture.  How do I show you the raw JSON response, if what I already included is not what you a looking for?

Comment: You show only the headers, not the body.

Comment: Really. Let me try again. Look at the response tab, is that not the raw JSON response or should I say the raw XHR response?  If it is not, then I don't know what is or how to show it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a lot of research, I was able to resolve my issue by using $http.jsonp() method instead of $http.get() method.  I guess I just overlooked the $http.jsonp() method because I am a newbie when it comes to make remote scripting request and really didn't know what JSONP was.

So now my new code looks like this:

```
$http.jsonp('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo',
                {
                    params: {
                        access_token: accessToken.token,
                        callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
                    }
                })
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    // Do something successful.
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    // TODO: Handle the error
                });
```

I would like to thank all who took the time to view my issue and those that responded to my question.  I hope this helps someone else that is new to AngularJS, JSONP, and Google OAuth2 like me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for the strange response is the fact that there is a space in the URL between ? and access_token.

I can't help you more than that with the why without a full testcase that I can run to reproduce your problem -- it doesn't reproduce for me on a local test.

Comment: I am not for sure where you are seeing a space in the URL.  I don't see a space from what I've posted here.  Please check end of post as I have updated to show a new picture of the chrome developers tool for the XHR request.  As you can see from the highlighted path, there are not spaces in the URL.  Please explain.  Thank you.

Comment: GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?
access_token=ya29.AHES6ZQBj6feCrXuDoqwA3FpX1T1HO8fH1eWegJbiBTp7Cs HTTP/1.1 -- has a space in it. Actually, it looks like a newline.

Answer (score 0):

Use angular 1.2.x and this won't happen. Apparently, angular 1.0.x is pre-flighting $http requests which google's tokeninfo service rejects.